# Can my employer see my investments?

Tags: investing

Going to start this off with making it clear I (US citizen working for US company) am not doing anything illegal, immoral, or against company guidelines with my investments. No insider trading, no shorting of my company's stock, no purchasing of commodity futures that are against the ethics guidelines, etc... I am just curious, does my employer have access to my investments in an online brokerage (ie not my 401k)? I don't have anything to hide but it just seems... overbearing that they would have access to those records. Like putting a camera in my office; I don't do anything wrong in my office, but I still wouldn't feel comfortable having a camera in there. I ask precisely because the ethics guidelines prohibit trading commodity futures associated with my company's business. The fact that that exists appears to indicate that they would have a way to see if an employee was engaged in this. Does that mean they can look at my investments?

Comment: Technically legal questions require jurisdiction but unless you live in a dictatorship this is answerable without.

Comment: Do you use your employer's equipment to view online accounts, and does your employee handbook specify what rights your employer retains with respect to use of their equipment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"The fact that that exists appears to indicate that they would have a way to see if an employee was engaged in this."

Are you suggesting that laws only exist when there is surveillance of your compliance? Petty theft is illegal even if there is no camera looking at the till.

To answer your question, no your employer cannot see your investment holdings unless you explicitly give them access.

Comment: If you use your work computer to look at your account information then someone in IT might see what you are doing. They are likely allowed to tell your boss “runeway uses his computer for private business”, but not what exactly you are doing. If you are not allowed to use your work computer for private business, that may be allowed even in countries with strong privacy rights.

Comment: @gnasher729 Knowing you check robinhood.com at work - seems quite likely to me. Checking how much money you invested in junk bonds - that seems like a major violation to me. If there is no limit to what your employer can store from your work computer activity, then does your employer also have the right to install a keylogger and pull your private email account password as well?

Answer (score 6):

For what it is worth, if you work in some regulated industries an employer CAN make you provide access to your investments for compliance checking. Mine does, as do most of the other big Accounting firms. They can't do anything except see what my investments are, not even sure if they see the dollar amounts.

At my company they download it every day and check it against our list of compliance so there is no possibility of conflict of interest where we are in a position to materially affect the financials of that company (through our audits), or where we have access to insider information.

I want to be clear, they did have to ask my permission to hook this system up and couldn't do it on their own, but it was a condition of employment.

Answer (score 3):

They have no way of getting electronic access unless you give it to them, or if they get a court order.

> Does that mean they can look at my investments?

Maybe. For some positions they can ask periodically for financial information. They are looking for items on your credit history/file that will point to a financial problem, that would show you as an insider threat.

They could also be looking for evidence that you have unexplained wealth, or other troubling investments. They could therefore ask for balances or statements. Of course they would not easily know about accounts you failed to mention, unless there was evidence in those other statements.

If they require this level of information they would notify you of these requirements during the hiring process, or in advance if the policy changes.

If they did require you to report this, they would also include a notice that failing to report everything could lead to disciplinary action including being fired.

Answer (score 1):

No, your employer can very likely not see your private investment portfolio. Not unless you are making those investments through the company itself (like with an employee stock options program).

Rules can exist even without an easy way to detect any infraction. Internal rules against insider trading exist in most publicly traded companies, because insider trading is not just unethical, it is in fact against the law. And when an employee gets caught engaging in it, then the company might get in trouble too. Having an internal policy which explicitly forbids it *might* help them to defend against allegations that they facilitate financial crimes committed by their employees.

Insider trading is already hard to prove. The prosecution has to prove beyond reasonable doubt that someone knew non-public information about their company **and** that that information had effect on the value of securities **and** that the defendant took trading actions based on that information they wouldn't have taken otherwise. A good attorney will in most cases be able to find some very reasonable sounding arguments which cast doubt on each of these three points. Still, laws against it are on the books.

1. As a moral deterrent. To make it clear for everyone that you are not supposed to do this
2. As a legal tool which can be used against people who do it so blatantly that it can be proven

Comment: At one company I worked they had the rule “you are not allowed to do anything that _creates the impression_ of insider trading” - after an employee was caught and it created bad press among other things. So if you did something that gets you into court, that would 99% be against the internal company rules because you certainly “created the impression” of insider trading.

Comment: @gnasher729 I see. The standard "don't get caught" policy.